# Handle web service response (error scenario)not working

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, web-services

```
function AddTheatres() {
  Services.AdminWebServices.AddTheatresSVC(oTheatres, OnSuccessTheatres, OnError, OnTimeOut);
}

function OnSuccessTheatres(result1) {
  Services.AdminWebServices.AddTicketPricesSVC(oTicketPrices, OnSuccessTicketPrices, OnError, OnTimeOut); //working
}

function OnSuccessTicketPrices(result2) {
  alert(result2); //not working
}
```

Why is the alert not working?
On Debugging the function calling `AddTicketPricesSVC` is returning correct value.

Comment: @splattne: I have deleted the earlier post and added new onw without community wiki.
Thanks for pointing out. :)

Comment: @splattne: Its just that I didnt know.
I thought wiki was something to just share.
didnt know about the point problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you implement the OnError and OnTimeout handlers? Maybe there is a server error?

Answer (score 0):

```
function OnError(error)
{
    alert(error.get_message());
}
function OnTimeOut()
{
    alert('System Time Out');
}
```

This is the way to implement it right?